# Windows Mobile WAP Wakeup

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, compact-framework, sms, sendmessage

could anyone please give me directions, or better - a working sample, of using the "WAP Wakeup" feature in Windows Mobile?

I'm trying to follow directions from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919167.aspx . Unfortunately, they only give the beginning of the solution.

Step 1: register your application to listen to SMS messages coming from a specific port.

Step 2: send an SMS message to that port

Step 3: the application opens up and sends a message to the application listener class window

Step 4: receive that message and bubble up an event

I am clueless about steps 2-4.. are those even the right steps?

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this myself but I have worked in a simlar area.

There are two ways to send the WAP SMS Message (basically a binary [Wireless Datagram Protocol (WDP)](http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/affiliates/wap/wap-259-wdp-20010614-a.pdf) formatted binary SMS message)

1. By Phone using the [WAP api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920063.aspx).
2. Using a SMS gateway.

A SMS Gateway allows you to send sms messages from the internet.  If you search on the web for SMS gateways you should get lots of them.  Pick one that supports sending Binary SMS Messages.

As part of the WDP header you have to specificy a port number, which is the port number they go on about.

Before you send the sms message, you need to check with your cellular provider that they support binary sms messages, not all cellular networks do.

The rest of it is pretty much following the [Microsoft Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919421.aspx):

> 1. Create the registry setting.
> 2. A WDP SMS messages arrives at the WDP layer on port WDPport1.
> 3. The WDP layer checks if the application is registered with the WDP
>      layer on Port Number WDPport1. In this
>      case, no application is registered.
> 4. The application checks the registry to determine if any application is
>      registered for WDP messages on Port
>      WDPport1., The application finds that
>      Chess.exe application is registered.
> 5. If Chess.exe is loaded, the application launches Chess.exe.
> 6. The chess application opens "ListenerWnd" Listener Window Class.
> 7. "ListenerWnd" receives a message with DWORD value
> 8. Chess.exe recognizes this message as an indication that a WDP message is
>      awaiting on port WDPport1 and
>      registers WDPport1 as it's own with
>      the WDP layer.
> 9. Chess.exe receives and processes the awaiting WDP message.
> 10. Chess.exe closes.

Answer (score 0):

i sent a binary sms by all rules, created a registry settings, application... all as written at the Microsoft forum about WAP Wakeup... but when mobile receives sms, its directly goes into Inbox.... 
may by anybody can tell on which aspects a need to make a point.. because.. 3 days on this problem.. this is not good :-(